# how to declare char * with input of {"data": "0001"}'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

my input data have this format { "data": "0001" }'. when I declare as follows, in VC, it showed msg of "user-defined literal operator not found". how to declare and initialize with this format?

```
const char * u = "{ "data": "0001" }'";
```

Comment: Escape the embedded double-quote characters? `const char * u = "{ \"data\": \"0001\" }'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C++11 onwards, you have the option of using [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

With that you will be able to do this:

```
const char * u = R"({ "data": "0001" }')";
```

If you cannot use C++11 features, then go for the old-fashioned way of escaping the double quotes like this:

```
const char * u = "{ \"data\": \"0001\" }'";
```