# How would I print quotation marks in the output in C++?

Tags: c++

I am beginning my C++ coding with challenges from the book *Exercises for Programmers* by Brian P.Hogan. I am capable of doing this, it's just I have never come across this int he 4 weeks I have been coding.

I am attempting to write a simple program that prompts the user for a quote, and the author of the quote. 
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::string quote;
  std::string author;

  std::cout << "Please enter a quote" << '\n';
  std::cin >> quote;
  std::cout << "Please enter the author" << '\n';
  std::cin >> author;

  std::cout << author << " said " << ""quote"" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> compile error
> ```

With the above code, it compiles wrong. This is because of the double quotation marks

```
std::cout << author << " said " << ""quote"" << '\n';
```

The desired output will look something like this

> ```
> What is the quote? These aren't the droids you're looking for.
> Who said it? Obi-Wan Kenobi
> Obi-Wan Kenobi says, "These aren't the droids
> you're looking for."
> ```

Notice the quotation marks on the desired output around the quote (how a quote should really look anyway). I have looked online, but haven't been able to find a solution specifically for C++.

What I am asking, is how do i display text in the terminal with quotation marks around it. (Like this - "hello")

I hope you understand the question. It is my first post and I tried to make it as clear as possible what the issue is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use escape sequence: "\"quote\""

Comment: Just escape them using a backslash `'\"'`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717597/how-to-declare-char-with-input-of-data-0001/53717729#53717729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escape the quote:

https://ideone.com/lcrYlA

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    // your code goes here
    std::cout << " hello " << " \"world\"" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can of course do:

```
std::cout << author << " said \" "<< quote << "\"\n";
```

Comment: I tried this, and it prints out "quote". However, I have quote defined as a variable which the user inputs. So if the user says Hello, it should print out "Hello", not "quote"

Comment: What about doing: std::cout << author << " said \" "<< quote << "\"\n";

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect. I didn't understand the escaping the quote, but now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the quote with \

```
std::cout << "the character \" is a quote";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the string using a backslash `\"` e.g `printf("Quotes \"\" ");`