# How to print quotation marks in c++

Tags: c++

Can I print "" in C++

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
cout << """ << endl;
return 0;      
}
```

Is there any way to print "

Comment: Yes. Escape it like so:: `"\""`

Comment: I dont know about c++ try to escape it by prefixing a  \"

Comment: yeah it's working

Comment: Documentation on [Escape characters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I print quotation marks in the output in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739760/how-would-i-print-quotation-marks-in-the-output-in-c)

Comment: problem  has been resolved

Comment: Or `std::cout << '"' << '\n';`. In case you can't read that, it's a double quote enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the " like this

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
cout << " \" " << endl;
return 0;      
}
```